# Unable to set background color as black for the parent div containing child divs

Tags: html, css

This is without height attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/karthik64/pFcpX/

And this with height attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/karthik64/pFcpX/1/

The problem is I need to set a fixed 'height' attribute to get background-color as black and if I remove the height attribute from the CSS property , the background-color wont be black. I have to tell you that the height of my div here, is a dynamic one. It depends on the data fetched from database.

I have tried `!important`, something like that, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the style of the outer `div`

See this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WXfyR/)

Comment: Hey thanks @wouterH it worked. but could you please explain me why overflow hidden works here. Iam intersted to learn the concepts.. Thanks

Comment: Well, your inner div is floating (`float: left`), that's why the outer div doesn't take over the size of the inner div (they're just floating around). When setting overflow to hidden on the outer div, you force it to take over that size.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed your code a little bit. I added a div just before the last closing div and added a class name clearfix. And add `clear:both` to clear fix class. Now you can use this class where ever you have floating div's.

HTML:

```
<div style="width:690px;background-color:#000000;margin-left:40px;margin-top:4px">


        <div style="float:left;width:310px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding-left:30px; color:#fff;"> 

        <div style="font-size:1.6em;margin-top:15px"> Hello! </div>

        <div id="iamm"> Niko </div>

        <div style="font-size:12px"> I'm a Student               </div>

        <div style="font-size:12px"> gender Male                 </div>

            <div style="font-size:12px"> I stay at India </div></div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pFcpX/9/

Comment: There's no need for this tricky `clear: both` here, `overflow: hidden` will do just fine and you don't have to add an unneeded div

Comment: Its just a method there are many others. As one used in HTML5 boilerplate.

Comment: just too bad, they still have no proper solution for this, so common problem, in HTML5

Answer (score 0):

Add below given css to your stylesheet & use this class clearfix where ever you face this problem. Its used in HTML5 Bolerplate.

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
```

Here is the fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/pFcpX/10/

I added this class clear fix to your top div with black background.